# Installation and execution of GDAL

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I am trying to install GDAL on the remote server.
I do:

```
pip install GDAL==1.9.1
```

It gets installed and then I try to do:

```
gdalinfo --version
```

But I get 'command not found'.

I understand that I have to write the environment variable in the .bash_profile script.

So I open the file with vim and I type:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH
```

And then:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

But still doesn't work.

I checked the location of my GDAL with: which ogr2ogr command and I get:

```
/usr/bin/which: **no ogr2ogr in** (/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/home/vagrant/.venvs/geonode/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/bin)
```

Comment: Did you check whether that framework folder exists? You can do a search for the executable: `find /Library -name gdalinfo` or `find /usr -name gdalinfo`

Comment: There is a GDAL-1.9.1 folder in home/src. So I guess the installation of GDAL is in this path. But how should I set the environment variable?

Comment: I think `pip` only installs the gdal python bindings. To install the complete gdal library and tools on OSX, you can use Kyngchaos or Homebrew.